# How to tell SVN to ignore files for all team members

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have various files that I want to be ignored by SVN when committing.  I know that I can go into TortoiseSVN and ignore them in various ways.  I know that I can run svn propedit svn:ignore from the command line to do the same thing.

The problem is that I have to have everyone on my team to do that, which is a pain.  Is there a way that I can put some file in a folder or set something in my SVN repository that tells it to never check a certain file in?

Comment: Nice question - curious about this myself.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Once you have setup your svn:ignore properties (either using TortoiseSVN or the commandline), you should commit these changes.

As soon as your team-members update their working copies, they will also have the svn:ignore properties set, and the files/folders listed in the properties will be excluded from commits.

See this page for details: [TortoiseSVN - Ignoring Files And Directories](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html)

Note:

If you have already commited some file which should be ignored, then you first have to [delete them from the repository](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-unversion.html) before you can ignore them (see rmeador's comment)

Comment: it's worth noting that svn:ignore only ignores non-versioned files.  If the files have already been committed, they will not be excluded from commits.  svn:ignore will also not prevent you from forcibly added the ignored files to version control.

Comment: If you set it to recursive when you add the properties though it will update all files and folders (big ass commit) but sorts out the problem mentioned above :o)

Answer (score 2):

An alternate approach that I use because I prefer not to litter my repositories with svn:ignore properties for *some* files (like IDE files, OS files, files to be ignored across multiple projects, etc.) is to keep a config file in a different repository. In that file, I set certain patterns in the global-ignores list. I then check out that config file to ~/.subversion and have my team members do the same.

By doing that, we all have the same global config file and it can be `svn update`d on an as-needed basis. I find this way useful when I have multiple projects going on (which is almost always) and they share many of the same strategies.

Answer (score -4):

Prepare a proper clean structure in SVN and then ask all users to checkout fresh.